# Как я могу получить доступ к элементу JSON объекта?

Tags: postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть  объект credSum, будет ли правильно если я обращусь следующим образом?
`pm.response.json().data.personalConditions.credSum;`  ?

Comment: `personalConditions[0].credSum`

Comment: Спасибо Рустам) вывел данные.